# Splitting array and export values in MATLAB / Octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have a large array where the amount of rows will vary, and I would like to split up and export to multiple files.

I was thinking of using the reshape command, but then I realized for this to work the arrays needed to have the same number of rows which will not always be the case.

```
clear all, clc,clf,tic
num_elm = 11;
num_elm_split = 4;  %Splits into columns
t = linspace(1, num_elm, num_elm)';

v = reshape(t, num_elm_split,[]); %Will split array into different columns
%'for' loop to split number of elements
for ii = 1:length(t(:, 1))
    ii
end
```

**Example:**

If I have an array of 11 values

```
a = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11]
```

And I want it be split up on every three values and output the data to a file.

**ouput1.txt** would have in it
**1
2
3**

**ouput2.txt** would have in it
**4
5
6**

**ouput3.txt** would have in it
**7
8
9**

**ouput4.txt** would have in it
**10
11**

I know I could use the [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) command in Linux, but I'm trying to use only MATLAB/[Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) code.

Comment: you could also pad with nan's until length is evenly divisible by `num_elm_split`. That way you could use RESHAPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to do it like this:

```
values = 1 : 11;
binSize = 3;
fileNum = 1;
n = numel(values);
for i = 1 : binSize : n
   part = values(i : min(n, i + binSize - 1));
   fprintf('File %d contains %s\n', fileNum, mat2str(part));
   fileNum = fileNum + 1;
end
```

Output:

```
File 1 contains [1 2 3]
File 2 contains [4 5 6]
File 3 contains [7 8 9]
File 4 contains [10 11]
```

You need to adapt the code in the loop to actually save the data on disk, of course.

Comment: that looks great but when I try and adapt it to append text before and after the data in the array gets exported I notice I can't.  Example if I want to have some text added before or after each value I export the data like a path "/tmp/file1.txt" and "/tmp/file2.txt" I can't since it's "bunching the data together" is there away to do this?

Comment: @RickT - it looks like you are adding another requirement that was not evident in your original question. Please update your question to make clear what you want - your comment in response to this solution is not very clear. As always - show what you did, what you got, and what you expected... Your "bunching the data together" comment needs clarification - what were you doing? Show your actual line of code.

Comment: @Floris thanks I figured it out I just added another for loop inside to loop through the part array
for jj=1:length(part)
  part_val=part(jj)
end

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code...this may help someone else out

```
clear all, clc,clf,tic
filesoxplaylistStr='1soxplaylist.pls'; %playlistist filename fix
dirplstmp='/tmp/tmp/';

values = 1 : 11;
binSize = 3;
fileNum = 0;
n = numel(values);
for ii = 1 : binSize : n
    part = values(ii : min(n, ii + binSize - 1))';
    fileNum = fileNum + 1
    %open file to write to
    fidsoxpl = fopen(strcat(dirplstmp,filesoxplaylistStr), 'w'); %create and open file to write to for sox playlist join file
    for jj=1:length(part)
        part_val=part(jj,1) %gets individual filename or values

        %create sox file to join
        fprintf(fidsoxpl,'File%s=%s%s.wav',num2str(jj),dirplstmp,num2str(part_val,'%06d'));%create playlist data file
        fprintf(fidsoxpl,'\n');

    end
    % close file to write to
    fclose(fidsoxpl);

    fn=strcat('test',num2str(fileNum,'%02d'));
    %join files with sox
    syscmd=strcat({'sox '},dirplstmp ,filesoxplaylistStr, {' '},dirplstmp,fn,{'.wav'});
    system(syscmd);

    %add freq to file name


end
```